# Saving and loading of Keras model not working

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've been trying to save and reupload a model and whenever I do that the accuracy always goes down.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(SURFACE_TYPES), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(
      train_ds, 
      validation_data=val_ds,
      epochs=EPOCHS,
      validation_steps=10)
```

Output:

Epoch 1/3
84/84 [==============================] - 2s 19ms/step - loss: 1.9663 - acc: 0.6258 - val_loss: 0.8703 - val_acc: 0.6867

Epoch 2/3
84/84 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 0.2865 - acc: 0.9105 - val_loss: 0.4494 - val_acc: 0.8667

Epoch 3/3
84/84 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 0.1409 - acc: 0.9574 - val_loss: 0.3614 - val_acc: 0.9000

This followed by running these commands to produce outputs result in the same training loss but different training accuracies. The weights and structures of the models are also identical.

```
model.save("my_model2.h5")
model2 = load_model("my_model2.h5")

model2.evaluate(train_ds)
model.evaluate(train_ds)
```

Output:

84/84 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0854 - acc: 0.0877

84/84 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0854 - acc: 0.9862

[0.08536089956760406, 0.9861862063407898]

Answer (score -1):

i have shared reference link [click here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/)

it has all formats to save & load your model